# Author doesn't explain this equals sign in $R(\theta)\stackrel{?}{=} R(\frac{\theta}{N})^N$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, group-theory, rotation

I am struggling to convince myself that the following relation holds:

$$R(\theta)\stackrel{?}{=} R\left(\frac{\theta}{N}\right)^N,$$

where:

- $R$ is an $SO(2)$ matrix
- $\theta$ is some finite angle.

Note: I got this from a relativity textbook (Einstein in a Nutshell, A. Zee)

Comment: Try the $U(1)$ analog 1st, where $R(\theta) = \exp{i\theta}$.

Answer (score 5):

Since $SO(2)$ is Abelian, 
$$R(\theta_1)R(\theta_2)=R(\theta_1+\theta_2)$$ and in particular $R(2\phi)=R(\phi)R(\phi)$ and thus $R(N\phi)=R^N(\phi)$ by induction.  Take now $\phi=\theta/N$.